# How to set a state (and persist after reload) in vuex using mutation?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm currently doing the login authentication part of a web app using Vue.js / Vuex and Laravel PHP.

After successful authentication, I want to call my userObject from the backend (attributes includes: email, role_id, etc.) and show specific attributes in the frontend (navbar component).

I have checked the localStorage and the userObject is stored there, but it seems it is not committed to my store (currentUser) (vue dev tools showed the currentUser{} is empty)

The following are my codes:

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Api from './_services/Api.js';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentUser: {},
  },
  mutations: {

    SET_CURRENT_USER(state, user) {
      state.currentUser = user;
      window.localStorage.currentUser = JSON.stringify(user);
    },
    LOGOUT_USER(state) {
      state.currentUser = {}
      window.localStorage.currentUser = JSON.stringify({});
    }
  },
  actions: {
    logoutUser({commit}) {
      commit('LOGOUT_USER')
    },
    async loginUser({commit}, loginInfo) { //store.js
      console.log(loginInfo)

      try {

      let response = await Api().post('/login', loginInfo);
      console.log(response)

      let user = response.data.user;
      console.log(user)

      commit('SET_CURRENT_USER', user);
      console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.currentUser));
      return user;


    } catch {

      return {error: "Email / Password combination was incorrect or unrecognized by the system. Please try again."}

    }


    }
  }
})
```

***navbar.vue***

```
<template>
    <nav>
<v-toolbar app :fixed="toolbar.fixed" :clipped-left="toolbar.clippedLeft" color="black">
<v-toolbar-side-icon class= "white--text" @click.stop="toggleMiniDrawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
<v-toolbar-title class="text-uppercase white--text" >
<v-btn flat to="/dashboard">
  <h1 class="font-weight-black display-1 white--text" >Activities</h1>

</v-btn>
</v-toolbar-title>
<v-spacer></v-spacer>
<h1 class="font-weight-regular title white--text">{{currentUser.name + ', ' + currentUser.email}}</h1>
</v-toolbar>

<v-list-tile @click="logoutUser">
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-icon class="black--text">exit_to_app</v-icon>
         </v-list-tile-action>
        <v-list-tile-content >
        <v-list-tile-title class="black--text">Logout</v-list-tile-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list-tile>
</v-flex>
</v-list>

</v-navigation-drawer>
</nav>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  data(){
    return{
    }
    },
    methods: {
      logoutUser () {
        this.$store.dispatch("logoutUser");
      }
      },
    computed: {
      ...mapState(['currentUser'])
    }
};

</script>
```

I tried explicitly putting data in the currentUser{} in store.js

`currentUser{name: 'Test', email: 'test@mail.com'}`

and it successfully displayed in the navbar.

This brought me to the conclusion that I weren't able to successfully put the userObject from 'user' to 'currentUser{}', or rather, it doesn't persist after reloads.

Thank you!

Comment: yes, `$store.*` does not persist on reloads, checkout [vue-realworld-example-app](https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/store/auth.module.js) for ideas how to handle that, but it really depends on how you auth with the api

Comment: At its core, the vuex store is just a regular JavaScript object. It amazes me how many people think that vuex is persistent storage. If you want something to persist across page loads, you need to use some form of persistent storage – either a cookie (client side) or a database (server side).

Comment: I use database (mySQL, PHP Laravel backend) to store data server side. My authentication method is through jwt (I was successful at getting JWT from the Server authentication via email / pass combination).

The server sends me back two object: token and userObject (which contains email, name, etc. as attributes).

I stored the userObject in "currentUser{}", although it doesn't seem to persist in vuex, but is still available in localStorage.

How would I be able to frequent call to localStorage so that it persists across reloads?